# empty (blank) fetch data return from php

Tags: javascript, php, fetch

I am sending an id by fetch to php to fetch the name of a project. Now when I am sending this result to console to verify that it brings it correctly but it only brings a blank or empty space. Thank you very much if you got this far

Javascript, where you capture the id by clicking and sending the id by fetch

```
var enlaces=document.getElementsByClassName('enlace');
for(let el of enlaces){
    el.addEventListener('click', obtener_id_proyecto);
}
function obtener_id_proyecto(e){
 e.preventDefault();
console.log('presionaste en un proyecto');
var id_p=this.id;

//Enviando datos por Fetch
let datos=new FormData();
datos.append('id', id_p);


fetch('inc/funciones/funciones.php',{
    method: 'POST',
    headers:{'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'},
    body: JSON.stringify(datos)
})
    .then(function(response) {
       if(response.ok) {
           return response.text();
       } else {
           throw "Error en la llamada Ajax";
       }
      })
    .then(function(datosRecididos){console.log(datosRecididos)});
}
```

PHP

```
function obtenerNombreProyecto(){
  $id_proyecto=$_POST['id'];

include 'conexion.php';
try{
    

    $sql= mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT nombre FROM proyectos WHERE id = {$id_proyecto}");
    return json_encode($sql);

} catch(Exception $e){
    echo "Error! : ". getMessage($e);
    return false;
}
```

}

Console screenshot

https://prnt.sc/9Cr8fKRuqAX1

Answer (score 1):

Probably there is a problem with this address: `'./inc/funciones/funciones.php'`. Are you sure about that? Why you put a `.` in the beginning of it?

Comment: Hey! I thought it was to get out of a directory (my mistake) but I tried without the ./ And  and still nothing. I will edit my code. Thank you for that

Comment: By the way the problem is probably from the server side. It will help to share your directory tree of server side app.

Comment: Do you want me to take a screenshot to the sidebar of the sublime text, where the different folders and files of my application are reflected? If I understood you correctly?

Comment: Yes. It would be fine.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, my JS file is in script.js and my php file is in functions.php                  
https://prnt.sc/9iPZxf2S3r4W

Comment: Which web server do you use and what is the root directory defined in the wwb server? If you can give me a screen shot of request header in the Network tab of browser's inspector, it will be great. If you want, you can send me an email to check the problem better. I'm curious about it.

Comment: The server I use is Xampp and I guess your main directory is htdocs (sorry if I'm wrong) I would like to, thanks, can I get your email from your profile or leave it in a comment?

Comment: Here is the capture https://prnt.sc/uio2WbwWww7n (i hope i understood you) I am waiting for your comment by my email kenlymar.p@gmail.com. Thanks again for your support

Comment: I'll be in touch with you by email